# Manual evaluation of `belongs 'a' ['a', 'b', 'c']`

Tags: haskell, evaluation, ghci

I'm trying to manually evaluate `belongs 'a' ['a', 'b', 'c']` where:

```
cuts :: [a] -> [([a],[a])]
cuts xs = zipWith splitAt [0..length xs] (repeat xs)

belongs x = any ((==x) . head . snd) . init . cuts
```

I start by evaluating `cuts ['a', 'b', 'c'] = [("","abc"),("a","bc"),("ab","c"),("abc","")]`

Then I apply `init` to the output of `cuts`:

```
init [("","abc"),("a","bc"),("ab","c"),("abc","")] = [("","abc"),("a","bc"),("ab","c")]
```

but then I get confused on how GHCi continue the evaluation.

PS: Note that `belongs` has the same semantics as `Prelude.elem`.

Comment: Can you evaluate `((==x). head . snd)("", "abc")`?

Comment: @Karolis Juodelė Yes I can, if x is 'a' the result is True. snd ("", "abc") = "abc", then head "abc" = 'a', then 'a' == 'a'. But the input in my expression is [("","abc"),("a","bc"),("ab","c")], not ("", "abc").

Comment: Well, `any` runs the same function for every item in the list, until it evaluates to `True`.

Comment: What is all that fuzz about? Wouldn't `belongs x = any (==x)` do the same?

Comment: @Bergi It was an example to understand how Haskell evaluate complex expressions.

Comment: OK, I just wanted to ensure that I didn't miss anything.

Comment: [Hint](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html) (You can also define your own `any`.)